# Cakephp 1.3 facebook login and check hostname [Need veteran advice]

Tags: php, facebook, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, facebook-login

I have this situation where user login via facebook needs to check on the `$_SERVER['HostName']` as in the database user table that keep records of particular user details might have **more than one row**. The difference is by the "hostname" (**to differentiate which subdomain from**).

In this situation I can login user with facebook without checking hostname when it comes to hostname I don't know where should I integrate the check of "hostname".

Any details that is needed to help understand the situation? I have been looking around for 2 days and no luck on the solution :/

**Facebook plugin** from [here](https://github.com/news2u/cakephp-social-sign-in)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure how you're using the hostname for the users, but I think you can use the scope setting to add the condition you're looking for:

```
'SocialSignIn.Facebook' => array(
    ...
    'scope' => array('User.hostname' => $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']), // or $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']
    ...
)
```

Comment: Very very close. It can't take HostName from that part not sure why it couldn't. It will work only if I put it in directly 'scope' => array('User.hostname' => 'Name_here_directly'),

Comment: Have you tried dumping `$_SERVER['HostName']` at that point to double check you're getting the value you're expecting?

Comment: Sorry, I had copied that bit from your question, but AFAIK it's not a real thing. Try it with `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` or `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` (answer updated).